# Is it a good idea to change a <div> to an <a> in order to make it clickable?

Tags: javascript

Can I change

```
 <div id="frame"></div>
```

for

```
 <a id="frame"></a>
```

or something will not work? The frame is a javascript background, I want it to be clickable. It works with a but is it the good way to do it?

---

Edit: I want to make

```
 <div id="frame"></div>
```

a

```
 <a id="frame"></a>
```

The frame is a Javascript background:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 images = [ 

 "Image1.gif",

 "Image2.gif",

 "Image3.gif"

];

function switchImage() {
var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
console.log(frame);
frame.style.background = 'url(' + images[getRandomNumber()] + ')';
}

function getRandomNumber() {

return Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
}

setInterval(switchImage, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean `<a id="frame"></a>`? Also you can just add a click event to the `div`.

Comment: You want it to be clickable for ... what? What is it expected to happen when the user clicks on it?

Comment: You can make almost any element clickable, and you can even control the cursor style with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, it's easy to make most types of element tags clickable. However, it's important to consider that a `<div>` is a block-level element by default, while an `<a>` is not. You may experience unintended layout effects if you change one into the other without correcting for it in your CSS.

Comment: Pretty sure that HTML5 opens up the `<a>` element to be used as a block level element. It also works in older browsers.

Comment: @squint I think that point would be more relevant if the asker had asked about wrapping the `<div>` in an `<a>`, which you are right, would work.

Comment: I see your point, though he did say it works, so I don't think layout is really an issue in the first place. I think he's asking about validity.

Answer (score 2):

The way to make a div "clickable" is to add an event handler to that JavaScript event, `onclick`.

As you describe it, you have a `div` with a background image that you want to make "clickable".

Just add the following JavaScript to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.getElementById("frame");
    obj.onclick = function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
        console.log('on-click event fired.');
    };
</script>

<!-- jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cfd110gy/1 //-->
```

The code you write within the `function` being attached to the `click` event will run each time the `#frame` is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/cfd110gy/1